# I cant access the req.user object data on passport js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am using [passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/) for my node/express project. I have used `authenticationMiddleware()`

I used it one of the routers.

I created logs to check data the user contains.

```
 console.log(req.user.username)
 console.log(req.user)
 console.log(req.user.last_name)
 console.log(req.isAuthenticated())
```

It outputs:

```
 undefined
 [ { account_no: 1,
      username: 'blairwaldorf',
      ....,
      last_name: 'Waldorf',
      ...,
      is_activated: 1 } ]
  undefined
  true
```

Why cant I access the data but I cant access the object?
Help. Thanksss :(

Answer (score 0):

```
[ { account_no: 1,
      username: 'blairwaldorf',
      ....,
      last_name: 'Waldorf',
      ...,
      is_activated: 1 } ]
```

You see this ?

The `[..]` means its an array, and to access an element in an array, you use `<array>[<index>]`.

so, you can access the element using `req.user[<index>].username`.
Note that its a 0 based indexing, so to get the first element, it will be `req.user[0].username`.

Comment: Thanks. Just follow up question. I forgot the index thing because the examples I found always uses req.user._id or they just use user.id. Why is that?

Comment: @CherylBlossom: So what is the "follow up question" ?

Comment: The examples I found doesnt put index on req.user._id or just uses user.id. They dont put indexes.

Comment: Cannot be sure of what examples you are looking at. Try the solution and find for yourself if it works.